# Getting error after submitting data using prepared statement with PDO connection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, pdo

I am trying to submit data to a database using AJAX with PDO connection but sometimes data are submitted sometime not. I am getting AJAX response empty.
Sometimes  I am getting  `$mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];` empty and if I refresh the page and again click on submit then data submitting

Also, I am getting some error. Would you help me in this?

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fillter\process.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\process.php(7): aus(Object(PDO))
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\process.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
```

**PDO connection**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Process.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date_of_added= date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

switch($_GET['key']) {
case 'aus':aus($conn);break;
default : redirect('index.php');
}
function aus($conn){
$emailtemplate=$_POST['emailtemplate'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];
$country="AUS";
$email_status=0;
global $date_of_added;
$sql ="INSERT INTO request(bulkemails, subjects, mailbody, country, email_status, date_of_send) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
//echo $sql;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssis", $emailtemplate, $subject, $mailbody,$country, $email_status, $date_of_added);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$(function() {
  $("form[name='bulkmailsend']").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
           emailtemplate:{
                 required: true,
           },
           subject: {
                required: true}
               },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            //form.submit();
        var emailtemplate = $('#emailtemplate').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var mailbody = $('#editor11').val();
        //alert(mailbody);
            $.ajax(
            {
               url:'process.php?key=aus',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                  'emailtemplate':emailtemplate,
                  'subject':subject,
                   'mailbody':mailbody
                 },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
            });
        }
    });

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="bulkmailsend" id="bulkmailsend">
  <textarea name="emailtemplate" placeholder="Enter email" id="emailtemplate"></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject">
    <textarea name="mailbody" id="editor11"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="addmail" id="addmail" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use MySQLi syntax for binding parameters but used PDO syntax to connect to the database. The reason you get an error `Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()` is because that method does not exist in PDO but in MySQLi ([`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)). Check the correct syntax for binding parameters [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) when using PDO.

In addition try changing accordingly your script. One way is by using named placeholders.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO request(bulkemails, subjects, mailbody, country, email_status, date_of_send) VALUES (:mailTemplate,:subject,:mailbody,:country,:email_status,:date_of_added)";
//echo $sql;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':mailTemplate', $emailtemplate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':mailbody', $mailbody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email_status', $email_status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':date_of_added', $date_of_added, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
// exiting
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
```

Another way is by using question mark placeholders.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO request(bulkemails, subjects, mailbody, country, email_status, date_of_send) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
//echo $sql;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $emailtemplate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $mailbody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $email_status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $date_of_added, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
// exiting
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below function to bind parameter.

```
<?php 

$sql = "INSERT INTO request(bulkemails, subjects, mailbody, country, email_status, date_of_send) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $emailtemplate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $mailbody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $email_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $date_of_added, PDO::PARAM_STR);
?>
```